# vue + flask - long running task on server

Tags: vue.js, flask, redis, vuex

i have a full-stack app - vuejs / vuex + flask + rq.
one of the flow - vue sends to backend data and there is a heavy/long-running task on the backend.
I am using Axios to communicate with the backend.
flow :
backend is using task queue and returns task_id; having task_id, I can check the status of the task when the status is ready I can proceed with the data on the client.

Question: what is the best way/practice on how to organize such flow. I think on - pooling task status every X milliseconds but I dought it is the best option.

Comment: Have you looked at web sockets?

Comment: web sockets, I will but I can't find a good working example. Also too many questions:
security, 
how many open sockets should I hold
what other potential edge cases should I pay attention